# Exit out from loop on incorrect password in expect TCL shell script

Tags: shell, rhel, expect, tcl

I have written a code snippet in TCL expect to connect from Server 1 to Server 2 using ssh. Users already may have set passwordless communication between Server 1 and Server 2, or it may ask for a password. Code should handle all these three below possible scenarios:

1. If passwordless login is enabled between Server 1 and Server 2
2. No Passwordless login is enabled, Password: prompt is displayed
3. If user enters incorrect Password, a second Password: prompt is expected where ctrl+c will be entered and will exit.

Please find below the code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
lassign $argv 1 2 
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $1@$2

expect {
      "*]#" { send -- "sleep 0\n" }  #Prompt when passwordless is active and user have logged in
      "Password: " {send -- "$2\n"   #Password prompt when no passwordless is active.
             exp_continue }
      "Password: " {send -- "^C" }   # Second Password Prompt when the wrong password is entered 
                                       in previous step. From here code should exit with a message
       }
 expect "*]#"                # After SSH is successful
```

I am not able to handle the second Password: prompt for an incorrect password where the code should exit with an appropriate message to the user. I am running the script ./testssh.exp username password.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
set count 0
expect {
    "Password:" {
        if {[incr count] == 2} {
            # this is the 2nd time, send Ctrl+C
            send -- \x3
            expect eof
            error "incorrect password"
        } else {
            send -- "$2\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    }
    "$prompt"
}
# successfully logged in.
send -- something 
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately it navigated to `# successfully logged in.
send -- something ` block even after wrong password